# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable error in python 3

Tags: python, regression, svm

I am using jupyter notebook python 3, and trying to iterate the values of Support vector regression hyperparameters simultaneously but got following error.

see figure below:

[TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW3AQ.png)

Comment: Could you share the code so we can look through it.

Comment: You're shadowing names - try `for x in C` and `for y in e` instead. Also, do take a look at how to ask questions with [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code reproduces your error.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> m = [5,6,7]
>>> for l in l:
        for m in m:
            print(l,m)


1 5
1 6
1 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in <module>
    for m in m:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You have to change the iterator variable names like this.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> m = [5,6,7]
>>> for l_i in l:
        for m_i in m:
            print(l_i,m_i)


1 5
1 6
1 7
2 5
2 6
2 7
3 5
3 6
3 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You maybe have to change iterative variable in order to be not same as list variable.
please change like this.

```
for i in C:
    for j in e:
        ...
```